# XQuery input error : document-node type where element expected, for WSO2 ESB

Tags: xpath, wso2, xquery, esb, wso2-esb

I have defined a Proxy Service on my WSO2 ESB that transforms incoming messages using XQuery (I am following [Sample 390](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample390)).

The problem is that the ESB transforms the variable `payload`, which is defined as `ELEMENT`, into an XQuery vairable defined as `document-node()`. But, my XQuery accepts only `element`() :

```
declare variable $payload as element(ns:payload) external;
```

Is there any way howto define the ESB variable or modify the variable expression so that the input into the XQuery is `element`?

I tried :

```
<xquery key="xquery-key-req">
<variable xmlns:nms="http://my.nms.com" name="payload" expression="$body/nms:payload" type="ELEMENT" />
</xquery>
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Required item type of first argument of xf:xqueryRequest() is element({http://my.nms.com}payload); supplied value has item type document-node(element({http://my.nms.com}payload))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you either have to change your query to expect a document node, or you have to change the client of the query to supply an element. I don't know ESB so I don't know how to make the change there, but changing the query is easy enough:

```
declare variable $payloadDoc as document-node(element(ns:payload)) external;
declare variable $payload as element(ns:payload) := $payloadDoc/ns:payload;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I was hoping for a solution that configures ESB to pass in an `element` but could not find it anywhere.